# Expo / React Native : Failing at creating my customized <Switch /> depending on platform

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, platform

I'm on Expo, and my problem is the color properties aren't the same on iOS and Android. I've done this (which works very fine):

```js
    //...
    const [hasAcceptedPolicy, setHasAcceptedPolicy] = useState(false);
    //...
    return(
       <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        {Platform.OS === "ios" ? (
          <Switch
            ios_backgroundColor={"red"} //just for example, I know it's ugly :p
            value={hasAcceptedPolicy}
            onValueChange={() => {
              hasAcceptedPolicy
                ? setHasAcceptedPolicy(false)
                : setHasAcceptedPolicy(true);
            }}
          />
        ) : (
          <Switch
            thumbColor={"blue"} //just for example, I know it's ugly :p
            value={hasAcceptedPolicy}
            onValueChange={() => {
              hasAcceptedPolicy
                ? setHasAcceptedPolicy(false)
                : setHasAcceptedPolicy(true);
            }}
          />
        )}
        <Text>I accept the policy.</Text>
      </View>
    )
```

I will reuse this at some other places, so I thought "Why not make my own component so I can call `<mySwitch />` wherever I want ?" Something looking this:

```js
import mySwitch from "./mySwitch";
    //...
    const [hasAcceptedPolicy, setHasAcceptedPolicy] = useState(false);
    //...
    return(
    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <mySwitch
            color={"blue"} //just for example, I know it's ugly :p
            value={hasAcceptedPolicy}
            onValueChange={() => {
              hasAcceptedPolicy
                ? setHasAcceptedPolicy(false)
                : setHasAcceptedPolicy(true);
            }}
          />
        <Text>I accept the policy.</Text>
    </View>
   )
```

My failed attempts lead to:

```js
//mySwitch.js
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Platform, View } from "react-native";

export default mySwitch = (color, value, onValueChange) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
      {Platform.OS === "ios" ? (
        <Switch
          ios_backgroundColor={color}
          value={value}
          onValueChange={onValueChange}
        />
      ) : (
        <Switch
          thumbColor={color}
          value={value}
          onValueChange={onValueChange}
        />
      )}
      <Text>I accept the policy.</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

When I press the switch, it never switches on, and the boolean `hasAcceptedPolicy` never becomes `true`.
What am I doing wrong ? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functional components props are an object.

Try to destructurate your component props like this :

```
export default mySwitch = (color, value, onValueChange)
```

to

```
export default mySwitch = ({ color, value, onValueChange })
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```js
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Platform, View, Text } from "react-native";

export default MySwitch = ({
  color,
  backgroundColor,
  title,
  value,
  onValueChange,
}) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
      {Platform.OS === "ios" ? (
        <Switch
          trackColor={{ false: null, true: color }}
          value={value}
          onValueChange={onValueChange}
        />
      ) : (
        <Switch
          thumbColor={color}
          trackColor={{ false: null, true: backgroundColor }}
          value={value}
          onValueChange={onValueChange}
        />
      )}
      <Text>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Where you want to call your component:

```js
    //...
    const [hasAcceptedPolicy, setHasAcceptedPolicy] = useState(false);
    //...
    return(
      <MySwitch
        color={hasAcceptedPolicy ? "#4285f4" : null}
        backgroundColor={"#a1c2fa"}
        title="I accept the terms and conditions."
        value={hasAcceptedPolicy}
        onValueChange={() => {
          hasAcceptedPolicy
            ? setHasAcceptedPolicy(false)
            : setHasAcceptedPolicy(true);
        }}
      />
    );
```